# Having the scrollbar appear only when the table is hovered on

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scrollbar, antd

I am working with a simple [antd table](https://ant.design/components/table/). I am trying to alter the scrollbar appearance of width / display by applying the css. Currently if you would see the small demo I have prepared here:

[image: Edit vigorous-saha-kstyr]

you would that the scrollbar always appears as shown here:

[image]

I want to show the scrollbar only when the user hovers over the table. What is the way to do this? I was trying to play around with the scrollbar behavior but nothing changed when I did (also in the index.css of the link shared):

```
.ant-spin-nested-loading::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: unset;
    display: block;
    width: 0.1px;
}
```

How could I only have the scrollbar when someone hovers over the table?

For convenience, I am also sharing the code here:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Table } from "antd";

const columns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name"
  }
];

const data = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "John Brown"
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "Jim Green"
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    name: "Joe Black"
  }
];

function jsx() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Table scroll={{ y: 80 }} columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(jsx(), document.getElementById("container"));
```

CSS that did not work:

```
.ant-spin-nested-loading::-webkit-scrollbar {
   background-color: unset;
   display: block;
   width: 0.1px;
}
```

Comment: i've opened code in codesandbox . the scrollbar is appearing only on hovering over the table. so, what's exactly is the problem ?

Comment: @sachinmathew It always appears for me!

Comment: @sachinmathew Could you suggest what could I do to alter the properties of the scrollbar like the background color and other properties?  I tried doing `.ant-spin-nested-loading::-webkit-scrollbar` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This CSS should work and it will be compatible across multiple browsers not just ones that support webkit prefixes.

```
.ant-table-body{
    overflow-y: hidden!important;
}

.ant-table-body:hover{
    overflow-y: scroll!important;
}
```